# Why are for loop and np.random.shuffle not work as expected in Python?

Tags: python, numpy, for-loop

I try to randomly shuffle the list in a for loop and then append it to another list. Expect to produce 5 lists in different orders, but the results are all in the same order. The code and output are as follows:

```
list_data = [] 
for i in range(10):
    list_data.append(i)
print(list_data)

# [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

```
random_list = []
for j in range(5):
    np.random.shuffle(list_data)
    random_list.append(list_data)
    print(list_data)
print(random_list)

# [6, 4, 5, 7, 8, 2, 0, 1, 3, 9]
# [2, 9, 4, 3, 5, 0, 7, 1, 6, 8]
# [3, 0, 9, 1, 5, 7, 8, 6, 4, 2]
# [6, 1, 7, 2, 0, 4, 9, 8, 5, 3]
# [3, 2, 5, 9, 8, 4, 6, 7, 1, 0]
# [[3, 2, 5, 9, 8, 4, 6, 7, 1, 0], [3, 2, 5, 9, 8, 4, 6, 7, 1, 0], [3, 2, 5, 9, 8, 4, 6, 7, 1, 0], [3, 2, 5, 9, 8, 4, 6, 7, 1, 0], [3, 2, 5, 9, 8, 4, 6, 7, 1, 0]]
```

Comment: You need to create a copy of the list using `random_list.append(list_data[:])`

Comment: Why are you using `np.random` to shuffle a list?

Comment: `np.random.shuffle` operates in-place.  So you are saving the same object to the list each time.  This is a common error in Python (not just with `numpy`).  When you collect items in a list, make sure each one is a distinct object (possibly with `copy`)

Comment: `random.random.shuffle` would have the same problem.  It shuffles in-place.  Looks like `np.random.shuffle` is much faster, even when working with a list. @juanpa.arrivillaga

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you already have an answer I'd like to help you shorten it into 3 lines of code, and you don't need numpy either. This can be achieved by list comprehension. This code below does what you want. 
Note: I used `random.sample` instead of `numpy.random.shuffle`, because that shuffles the list inplace and returns None.

```
import random
list_data = [i for i in range(10)]
random_list = [random.sample(list_data, len(list_data)) for j in range(5)]
```

Comment: There is no need for a list comprehension either. `[i for i in whatever]` should just be `list(whatever)` list comprehensions are for mapping/filtering operations

Comment: And in this case, you don't even need to create that list in the first place, you can just use the range object directly

Comment: Yes, it can be just```random_list = [random.sample(range(10), 10) for _ in range(5)]```.